# procurar um campo de formulário com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um campo select em html, o mesmo está oculto junto com uma div e desabilitado.

A partir da seleção de um valor (select), o mesmo deverá aparecer na tela e ser habilitar.

Não estou conseguindo fazer o campo select habilitar, sempre aparece desabilitado.

```
 $('#'+div).find(':select').prop('disabled', false);
```

estou usando ó código acima para procurar o select dentro de uma div e seto o disabled para false. Eu sei que o :select não é suportado. gostaria de saber como procurar um campo tipo select dento de um div.

Códigos HTML E JS:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Finalidade</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6" id="ocultar">
        <select name="finalidade" class="chosen-select input-md form-control" required>
          <option value="" selected>Selecione uma Finalidade</option>

        </select>
     </div>
</div>
<div id="ocultar_div" style="display: none;">
    <fieldset>
       <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Colaborador</label>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                 <select name="colaborador" class="chosen-select input-md form-control" required disabled>
                     <option value="0" selected>Selecione um Colaborador</option>

                 </select>
             </div>
     </div>
  </fieldset>
```

JS:

```
$("select[name=finalidade]").change(function(){
       var tipo = $(this).val();
       var iddiv = $("select[name=finalidade]").parent().attr('id') + '_div'; 
       MostrarEsconderDiv(tipo,iddiv);
    });

function MostrarEsconderDiv(tipo, div) {
    var elemento = $("#"+div).find("select");
    if (tipo == 3) {      
      $("#"+div).css("display", "block");
      elemento.prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $("#"+div).css("display", "none");
      elemento.prop("disabled", true);
    }

}
```

Comment: `select:hidden` no lugar de `:select`

Comment: Em vêz de `.prop('disabled', false);` testa `.removeAttr('disabled')`.

Comment: obrigado. preciso também desabilitar em determinadas situações, não apenas habilitar

Comment: Seria interessante postar a estrutura html para analisamos se esta pegando o seletor div corretamente também.

Answer (score 1):

O problema tá no `find`, altere para `.find('select')`

[Exemplo online](https://jsfiddle.net/tretaa/px3hz8L8/)

**EDIT:**

Não tem erro nenhum no seu código... creio que seja apenas um erro no html de onde esteja o seu `select` de `name="Finalidade"`... faltou você postar ele...

Mas já coloquei uma atualização neste [Exemplo Online](https://jsfiddle.net/tretaa/px3hz8L8/1/) exatamente como sua implementação deve ser...

Comment: fiz isso e mesmo assim o select continua desabilitado

Comment: @lelopes, posta então como está todo o ciclo, desde o html à chamada JS. Lembrando que, o exemplo que eu coloquei, não vai "aparecer" na tela, em caso de `display: none` ou `visibility: hidden` do `select`

Comment: @MarllonNasser postei os códigos com sua sugestão

Comment: @lelopes, na proxima vez você edita a sua pergunta e adiciona o código HTML.... E faltou você postar o HTML de onde o seu `select` de `name="Finalidade"` está, creio que o erro está nele.. editei a resposta com outro exemplo online pra você ver que está tudo certo :)

Comment: @MarllonNasser: ja corrigi e postei o código do select.

Comment: boa! você viu o novo exemplo online que eu coloquei na resposta? Tá tudo certo, amigo.... até com seu HTML... ainda não está funcionando? qual navegador vc tá usando? tá carregando o jQuery corretamente?

Comment: @MarllonNasser: vi seu exemplo funcionando perfeitamente. No meu não está funcionando, estou usando o chrome. o jQuery está carregando direito pois está ocultando e mostrando a DIV normalmente, apenas não habilita o select quando mostra o DIV.

Comment: Tenta com `elemento.attr('disabled', 'disabled');` para desabilitar e `elemento.removeAttr('disabled');` para habilitar.